# How am I receiving a trickle of rep from these upvotes after being repcapped?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

I've repcapped today, but am still seeing a trickle of rep coming through from my answers. It's hard to be sure, but I *appear* to have received +3 rep from 3 upvotes on an answer. Usually, of course, this would be +30 rep.

[image]

Is this a new rule, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Right now your daily rep shows +217, counting a downvote and an accept. I am all puzzlement.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: It's weird, right? I'm not imagining it?

Comment: Yeah, the fact that it's not counting older votes first and apparently not respecting cap either is very strange.

Comment: It's just gone down to +215 on its own. Must be CACHING....

Comment: Apparently the caching on my end disagrees, even after Ctrl-F5, and continues showing +217 on the [rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit?tab=reputation).

Comment: Do... you happen to be downvoting answers? (if I remember correctly, rep losses due to downvotes are private, so only you could see it in your rep tab)

Comment: @hichris123: I have done but that doesn't account for the "+3" in the notifications dropdown, as far as I know? I've apparently now got +18 from that question overall, through 3 answer upvotes and an accept. Just WTF in general, basically.

Comment: Maybe it's a display bug? Weird. What does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation show?

Comment: @hichris123: I've never been sure how to read that page. If it turns out to be a display bug then feck it fine I'll see whether it goes away and if not maybe promote this to a bug report with as much detail as I can piece together. In the meantime, I was wondering whether a rule has changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Events seem to have happened in the following order or similar:

- You receive 199 cappable¹ reputation in some way, including 30 for an answer to *What does return alone does in C++?*
- **12:43:** You receive an upvote for an answer to *What does return alone does in C++?* and hit the reputation cap. You now have +31 reputation on the latter question.
- You receive some more upvotes not granting you reputation.
- **15:14:** You receive a downvote on your answer to *What does return alone does in C++?* (visible in your [public reputation breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit?tab=reputation)). You now have +197 cappable reputation for the day, including +29 on *What does return alone does in C++?*
- **15:14 – 15:56:** You receive no further upvotes (I checked). At some time, you downvote an answer to *C++ operator == overloading.*
- **15:56:** You receive an upvote for an answer to *Will a C compiled .so work with a C++ application?* You get +3 and hit the reputation cap again.
- You receive two further upvotes on *Will a C compiled .so work with a C++ application?* not granting reputation.
- You make your screenshot.

Note how the last relevant events are:

1. Received vote on your answer to *What does return alone does in C++?*
2. Downvoted an answer to *C++ operator == overloading.*
3. Received vote on your answer to *Will a C compiled .so work with a C++ application?*

This matches the order of the most recent items in the achievements dropdown from your screenshot.

---

<sup>¹ i.e., reputation subject to the reputation cap</sup>

Comment: Hah, well done! Good enough for me.